# Specify go build directory when debugging in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, launch

I'm trying to set up go development in Visual Studio Code, but I can't figure out how to specify build directory in the launch config. I have a few DLLs required by the compiled binary, which are in the `lib` directory, so ideally I'd like to build to and debug from that directory. My initial `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "go",
      "request": "launch",
      "mode": "auto",
      "program": "${fileDirname}",
      "env": {},
      "args": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I managed to set the build path to be in the `lib` directory by adding `-o ../lib/${workspaceFolderBasename}.exe` to the `buildFlags`, but when I did that it complained that it couldn't find the built binary and I couldn't find a way to specify which binary to debug.

```
could not launch process: open d:\Users\<User>\Desktop\<project>\src\__debug_bin: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also thought about copying the DLLs from the `lib` directory, but I don't know how I would do that in the launch configuration file. Currently I can work around this issue by copying the DLLs manually to the `src` directory, but that's far from the ideal solution.